# Workflow not respecting filepath variable defined in function

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use Workflow to run two functions in parallel. This scripts reaches out to my Nuget package repository, grabs the version, and then inserts those version numbers into a download URL. I want to set $directory so that I can change the filepath easily. When running the following, the jobs run in parallel correctly, but they're deploying the folders to C:\ rather than C:\Temp. If I define the path as its literal path, it works fine, and if I just execute the functions with no workflow, it works fine. Any thoughts?

```
$directory = 'C:\Temp'

function getPackage1 {
    param ()
    $api = 'http://localhost/nuget/PackageName/Packages()?$format=json&$filter=id%20eq%20%27Package.Dotnet%27%20&$select=Version'
    $responses = (Invoke-RestMethod $api).d.results.Version
    foreach($response in $responses)
        {
            Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost/nuget/PackageName/package/Package.Dotnet/$response -OutFile (New-Item "$($directory)\package\$response.nupkg" -Force)
        }
}

function getPackage2 {
    param ()
    $api = 'http://localhost/nuget/PackageName2/Packages()?$format=json&$filter=id%20eq%20%27Package.Dotnet2%27%20&$select=Version'
    $responses = (Invoke-RestMethod $api).d.results.Version
    foreach($response in $responses)
        {
            Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost/nuget/PackageName2/package/Package.Dotnet/$response -OutFile (New-Item "$($directory)\package2\$response.nupkg" -Force)
        }
}

workflow getAllPackages {
    param ()
    parallel {
        getPackage1
        getPackage2
    }  
}

try { getAllPackages }
catch {'An unspecifed error occurred while downloading the files'}
```

Comment: Is your motivation for trying to run them in parallel that you want the overall script to complete faster? If so, workflows are _definitely_ not the tool to use, they're slow as hell :)

Comment: Pretty much that. Happy to hear suggestions on what I should be looking towards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## *Workflow's are terrible for "speeding up" things, see below*

---

### You need to pass all input to a workflow explicitly!

Workflows are designed to execute separate from the calling process, and for that reason commands and input values are serialized (turned into XML basically) before executing.

You must therefore explicitly pass everything referenced inside the workflow as parameters, it won't have direct access to the calling scope at runtime:

```
function getPackage1 {
    param($directory)
    # ...
}

function getPackage2 {
    param($directory)
    #...
}

workflow getAllPackages {
    param($directory)
    parallel {
        getPackage1 $directory
        getPackage2 $directory
    }  
}

try { getAllPackages $PWD.Path } catch { <# ... #> }
```

---

As the first header alludes, workflow's are pretty slow (and complicated), so if you're simply trying to speed up downloading all the files, you might as well just fork out the requests to new processes with `Start-Job`:

```
function Get-PackageVersions
{
    param ([string]$Destination)

    $api = 'http://localhost/nuget/PackageName/Packages()?$format=json&$filter=id%20eq%20%27Package.Dotnet%27%20&$select=Version'

    $responses = (Invoke-RestMethod $api).d.results.Version

    $Jobs = foreach($response in $responses)
    {
        Start-Job { Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost/nuget/PackageName/package/Package.Dotnet/$using:response -OutFile (New-Item "$($using:Destination)\package\$using:response.nupkg" -Force) }
    }

    # Wait 30 seconds for jobs to complete
    $completedJobs = $Jobs |Wait-Job -Timeout 30
    $Jobs |Remove-Job 
    if(-not $completedJobs){
        throw "Did not finish downloading all $($Jobs.Count) versions in time"
    }

}
```

Then pass your argument like:

```
$directory = "C:\target\folder"
Get-PackageVersions $directory
```

Comment: Using Start-Job, I've set it up like your example and it still isn't respecting my $directory variable I set outside of the functions. I can set the variable within each function, but would rather make it a single place to be set outside of the functions. Any thoughts?

Comment: You don't need to _set it_ to anything in each function, you just need to _declare_ it as a parameter. Note that I'm using the `using:` prefix inside the `Start-Job` scriptblock (otherwise we'll have same issue as with the workflows)

Comment: That was it, I wasn't passing the argument correctly. Thanks!